# instagram api: how to get the recent media added

Tags: instagram-api

I just managed to get the access_token for instagram api.

in flickr-api we have flickr.photos.getRecent to get the recent media

similarly in instagram how to get the recent media which from public_content

Also how to get the recent video from public_content.

Answer (score 0):

if you want public content (real). you must create submission to instagram. aliternative way is, you can "simulate" it on sandbox mode, but it limited only for 10 users.